# looping through cypress elements based on text

Tags: typescript, testing, cypress

The page I am trying to test has multiple buttons with text `Order` on it. I am trying to fetch all these buttons and loop though them.

I can't use `cy.get('button).contains('Order')` as it will only return the first button. Is there a way to do this?

I even tried to loop all buttons

```
cy.get('button').each(($button, index) => {
    if ($button.text() == 'Order') {
        cy.wrap($button).click();
    }
});
```

but this throws an error on the second button

`cy.click() failed because this element is detached from the DOM.`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe buttons are re-rendered after first click. Is it possible for your case?

Comment: Yes it is re rendering, in my case. But even after re rendering, all the buttons exist. So, is it possible to click on each button just once, based on the text of the button.

Comment: Unfortunately you have to get buttons again after each re-rendering. If DOM structure is the same after each re-rendering you can find all buttons and store full xpath for each button that you need. After that, you should do loop through stored xpaths and get next button before each click.